# Extracting tab data with Regex

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, text-extraction

I'm writing a web script to scrape data from guitar tabs and convert it into MIDI notes.

This is what the extracted tab data looks like. in string form:

```
[tab]e|------------------------------------------------------------------------|\r
\nB|----------3------5-------3----------------------------------------------|\r
\nG|---2-4---------------4----------4-2-0-----------------------------------|\r
\nD|---------------------------------------0---------------0-0--------------|\r
\nA|-----------------------------------------------------2------------------|\r
\nE|------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to be able to convert this visual representation of a guitar neck into a dataframe with 6 rows (e,B,G,D,A,E)

I'm looking for away to use regex to extract the relevant tab information and convert it into a dataframe.

For example,

1. Select all characters between "e|" and "|"
2. Store these characters in a 1xn dataframe

I cannot figure out how to do this for the life of me and its very frustrating.

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following:

```py
import re
import pandas

txt="""
[tab]e|------------------------------------------------------------------------|\r
\nB|----------3------5-------3----------------------------------------------|\r
\nG|---2-4---------------4----------4-2-0-----------------------------------|\r
\nD|---------------------------------------0---------------0-0--------------|\r
\nA|-----------------------------------------------------2------------------|\r
\nE|------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
pattern=r"(?<=e\|)[^|]*(?=\|%s)"%"\r"

matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
dataframe=pandas.DataFrame([matches])
```